# Different colors for grouped tableView and tableViewCell backgrounds

Tags: iphone, ios, uicolor, uitableview

How can I set **different colors** for **GROUPED UITableView inside background vs. background**, which is outside my table? That is the part which is visible when tableView is smaller than the screen or scrolled beyond limits of table.

**UPDATE**: that sample image is generated by my current code! I DO NOT NEED TIPS HOW TO MAKE IT !!! Please read the question before you (try to) answer. Would really appreciate this, but thanx anyway.

File AboutViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[CustomView alloc]
  initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds]; // VISIBLE
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // NOT VISIBLE
```

}

In the sample image (generated by my current code) the background view contains sample gradient from yellow to green, each cell "bubble" background is texture, each label has own background - all this just to demonstrate what I could define. As you can see, background gradient is partially visible through each cell and remains static when you scroll the table.

**What I want to do:** I want DIFFERENT tableView background for GROUPED UITableView.

For plain UITableView style I have defined a custom background for each cell, but it doesn't seem to work with GROUPED tableView. This only sets the cell background inside the cell "bubble". How to define the cell area outside that cell "bubble"?

[image]

Comment: Since people appear to be struggling to understand your question, perhaps you could put some arrows and explanation on your image? As far as I can tell you want a different colour to appear in the stretchable area that appears when you scroll the table off the top or bottom of the screen (different top and bottom, or just different to the table?) but you've lost me with the "cell bubble". Some arrows and letters would go a long way here.

Comment: You are right, picture update will definitely help! On the other hand the question is really a tough one, seems to be "feature" of grouped UITableView... Just got to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

For this u set `cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor redColor];` its work

and for background u tale image or set color

Comment: Not answering my question at all. This code can be used to define background inside "cell bubble", as I have done in sample pic. Want to know how to define cell background outside that "bubble".

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the image as backgroundimage.
But I think you are using the grouped table,so
you need to go with the tableview background color 
and set that to image color.
Like

```
winTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:@"bg.png"];
```

Or you can even go with the Gradient layer,inserting that in you view.
Hope this will help you.

Get the image of different color as you want to show the background of your table view.

Comment: Not answering my question. This code can be used to define tableView background, as I have done in sample pic. Want to know how to define DIFFERENT background color for tableView vs tableCell in grouped table.

Comment: Then you can even go with Gradient layers ,using gradient for your table view or table view cells

Comment: Because the image which you have put is showing different color on the view,so i answered according to that,its not showing the different colors on table view cells..

Comment: Gradient layer was a good tip, can change coloring of tableView. Still transparent and displays background through, but definitely an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

For cell color or view you can also use these.
Try to have different color for different cells by your logic.

```
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        //cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        UIView *backroundSelecView=[[[UIView alloc]init]autorelease];
        backroundSelecView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:203.0/255.0f green:218.0/255.0f blue:140.0/255.0f alpha:.80];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView=backroundSelecView;
        cell.backgroundView=[[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table-grid@2x.png"]]autorelease];
```

Comment: This is how to customize a cell normally, but when used in GROUPED tableView the rounded corners disappear. Also doesn't have any effect in areas before and after the cell (horizontally i.e. same table row).